Is there a way to MODIFY the diagonals (not just the centeral diagonal) of a matrix A by using just np.diag()?
Is there a way to MODIFY the diagonals (not just the centeral diagonal) of a matrix A by using just np.diag()? (so not using np.fill_diag() ). Im not sure how to do a diagonal above the center diagonal for example. I can access the other diagonals but not able to edit them using just np.diag(). Any methods?
I tried using np.diag() and could read the other diagonals but not change them. Ulitmatly i had to use this super skethcy for loop to change them manually. np.fill_diag() worked for just the main center diagonal but not the others. So help would be nice!

The source of np.diag shows that it makes a zeros array and fills it with a res[:n-k].flat[i::n+1] = v expression.  I'd have to work out the details later, but this shows it's possible to index any diagonal with this kind of flat expression.

Can you share a simple example that shows what your goal is and what you've tried?

You can just use fill_diagonal with a slice of your array to shift the diagonal:
import numpy as np

M, N = 4, 5

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

A = rng.random((M, N))
print(A)

np.fill_diagonal(A[:, 1:], 0) # Shifts diagonal 1 `horizontally`
print(A)

Output:
[[0.63696169 0.26978671 0.04097352 0.01652764 0.81327024]
 [0.91275558 0.60663578 0.72949656 0.54362499 0.93507242]
 [0.81585355 0.0027385  0.85740428 0.03358558 0.72965545]
 [0.17565562 0.86317892 0.54146122 0.29971189 0.42268722]]
[[0.63696169 0.         0.04097352 0.01652764 0.81327024]
 [0.91275558 0.60663578 0.         0.54362499 0.93507242]
 [0.81585355 0.0027385  0.85740428 0.         0.72965545]
 [0.17565562 0.86317892 0.54146122 0.29971189 0.        ]]


No, the purpose of np.diag in NumPy is to create or extract a diagonal from a 2D array. It does not directly handle changing non-central diagonals of a matrix; instead, it can either return the diagonal of an array or generate a diagonal matrix from a specified array.

I noted from the np.diag source, that it accesses diagonals with flat indexing.  It makes its own zeros array, but we can modify that to work with our own array.
To illustrate on a (3,3) array
In [162]: res=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3); res
Out[162]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

Modifying the main diagonal, accessing every n+1 element:
In [163]: res.flat[0::4]=[-1,-2,-3];res
Out[163]: 
array([[-1,  1,  2],
       [ 3, -2,  5],
       [ 6,  7, -3]])

and one above by changing the starting point:
In [164]: res.flat[1::4]=[-4,-5];res
Out[164]: 
array([[-1, -4,  2],
       [ 3, -2, -5],
       [ 6,  7, -3]])

and one below:
In [165]: res.flat[3::4]=[-6,-7];res
Out[165]: 
array([[-1, -4,  2],
       [-6, -2, -5],
       [ 6, -7, -3]])

np.diag_indices uses flat with arange
In [172]: res.flat[np.arange(3)*4]
Out[172]: array([-1, -2, -3])

In [173]: res.flat[1+np.arange(2)*4]
Out[173]: array([-4, -5])

So does np.diagflat.
